# html div background image not showing up

Tags: html, css, background

I'm working on a webpage (I'm a newb of course) and the background image won't show up in the div. I tried both background-image and background and they both will not work... heres the code

if anyone can help that would be great!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
body {background-color:gray;}
</style>
  </head>
<body>
  <div style="background-image: url('/ximages/websiteheader1.png');height:200px;width:1200px;">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you double check that you have the right path to your image?

Comment: I do, I've checked more than three times

Comment: @AbdulAhmad you should check a fourth time cause that's your issue.

Comment: yeah it definitely is, i just ran your script with a different link and the image showed up fine

Comment: lol ok... here's a question, should I include an absolute path or just keep the relative path (I've tried both but nothing seems to be working)

Comment: Depends, where is this HTML file relative to the image?

Comment: the image is in a sub-folder relative to the html

Comment: ok it's showing up, thank you guys

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I recommend moving your css from the inline scope.
Assuming that your .png file actually exists, try setting the background size and repeat tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
body {background-color:gray;}
#mydiv {
   background-image: url('/ximages/websiteheader1.png');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-size:contain;
   height:200px;width:1200px;
}
</style>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="mydiv">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If that doesn't work, try checking in your browser's developer tools for the response codes and making sure that the url is correct.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 21):

A fast refresher about **paths**

### Absolute paths

`https://website.com/assets/image.jpg`

---

`//website.com/assets/image.jpg`
image loaded using http or https protocols

---

### Relative paths

(For *internal use* if the image is on the same server)

---

`image.jpg`
**image** in the same folder as the document calling the image!

---

`./image.jpg`
Same as above,  **image** in the same folder as the document calling the image!

---

`/assets/image.jpg`
**Similar to Absolute Paths, just omitting the protocol and domain name**
Go search my image starting from my root folder `/`, than into `assets/`

---

`assets/image.jpg`
this time **assets** is in the same place as the document, so go into **assets** for the image

---

`../assets/image.jpg`
From where the document is, go **one** folder **back** `../` and go into `assets`

---

`../../image.jpg`
go **two** folders **back**, there's my image!

---

`../../assets/image.jpg`
go **two** folders **back** `../../` *and than go into* `assets`

Answer (score 1):

For me it was because i was using an angular element directive to set the background but i forgot to set "display" to "block".  Ugh! I spent forever troubleshooting this!  Had it been an attribute directive i likely would not have encountered this.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

### No overriding

Make sure no other classes or styles overwrite what you want.

### The path to your image

Replace the link of your image with a web image **to check if the problem is the path or not**. You can try this Bootstrap [home](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/house-door-fill/) icon.

```css
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor">
  <path d="M6.5 14.5v-3.505c0-.245.25-.495.5-.495h2c.25 
  0 .5.25.5.5v3.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h4a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-7a.5.5 0 0 0-.146-.354L13 5.793V2.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.293L8.354 1.146a.5.5 0 0 0-.708 0l-6 6A.5.5 0 0 0 1.5 7.5v7a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h4a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5z"/>
  </svg>');
```

### Icon is shown correctly

You need to add some properties like

```css
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
padding: 1rem;
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
I corrected the relative path to start from the same folder as the page and it worked:
    url(./images/1.jpg) instead of url(/images/1.jpg)
I read somewhere that it's better to do so always.
let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

actually, the same problem has gone with me. 
the solution is here for that problem. 
you have to change your path 
 `background-image: url('/ximages/websiteheader1.png')`;
             TO
 `background-image: url('ximages/websiteheader1.png')`;

actually, remove the first `/` from the path of the image.