# JQuery: Change background image if a radio button gets checked

Tags: jquery

How do I change the background image of a element if a radio button gets `checked`

Please take a look at my example below.

```js
$("#outside input:radio").change(function(){
$("#color-outside").css("background-image", ($('#outside input:checked').data("image")));
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="color-outside" style="background-image: url();"></div>


<div class="swatch-element black">
<input id="black" type="radio" name="contact[Farbe Innen]" value="black" data-image="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1329/9539/t/2/assets/schwarzblau.png?5811407930308074056" checked="checked" /> 
<label for="schwarz"></label>
</div>

<div class="swatch-element white">
<input id="white" type="radio" name="contact[Farbe Innen]" value="white" data-image="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1329/9539/t/2/assets/weiss.png?5811407930308074056"/> 
<label for="white"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: You do this kind of selection `$("#outside input:radio")`. Where is the element with the `outside` id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input:radio").change(function(){
$("#color-outside").css('background-image','url('+ $(this).data("image")+')');
});
});
```

```css
#color-outside{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="color-outside"></div>


<div class="swatch-element black">
<input id="black" type="radio" name="contact[Farbe Innen]" value="black" data-image="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1329/9539/t/2/assets/schwarzblau.png?5811407930308074056" checked="checked" /> 
<label for="schwarz"></label>
</div>

<div class="swatch-element white">
<input id="white" type="radio" name="contact[Farbe Innen]" value="white" data-image="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1329/9539/t/2/assets/weiss.png?5811407930308074056"/> 
<label for="white"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input:radio").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#color-outside").css("background-image", "url(" + $(this).data("image") + ")");
    }
});
```

Note that you need to bind the `change` event to both radio buttons. Also, since the `change` event is **not** fired when a radio button gets unchecked, you can omit the `.is(":checked")` conditional, so the code would be even shorter.

```
$("input:radio").change(function() {
    $("#color-outside").css("background-image", "url(" + $(this).data("image") + ")");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your given HTML there no element  with id `outside`. You need to put background image url in `url("")`. Try like following.

```js
$(".swatch-element :radio").change(function() {
    $("#color-outside").css("background-image", "url(" + $(this).data("image") + ")");
});
$(".swatch-element :radio:checked").change(); //execute change event for checked radio button
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swatch-element black">
    <input id="black" type="radio" name="contact[Farbe Innen]" value="black" data-image="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1329/9539/t/2/assets/schwarzblau.png?5811407930308074056" checked="checked" />
    <label for="schwarz"></label>
</div>

<div class="swatch-element white">
    <input id="white" type="radio" name="contact[Farbe Innen]" value="white" data-image="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1329/9539/t/2/assets/weiss.png?5811407930308074056" />
    <label for="white"></label>
</div>

<div id="color-outside" style="height: 200px; width:330px; background-size: cover;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On change of radio button selected got the data-image attribute of selected radio button and set the image in the div's backgroud image.

To apply background image for div you should have to give some other css property as well. Please refer [html div background image not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272395/html-div-background-image-not-showing-up) and please check snippet for more details.

```js
$("input[type='radio']").change(function(){  
  $("#color-outside").css("background-image",'url(' + $(this).data("image") + ')');
});
```

```css
#color-outside{
   background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1329/9539/t/2/assets/schwarzblau.png?5811407930308074056");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="color-outside" >
  lorem ipsum
</div>


<div class="swatch-element black">
<input id="black" type="radio" name="contact[Farbe Innen]" value="black" data-image="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1329/9539/t/2/assets/schwarzblau.png?5811407930308074056" checked="checked" /> 
<label for="schwarz"></label>
</div>

<div class="swatch-element white">
<input id="white" type="radio" name="contact[Farbe Innen]" value="white" data-image="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1329/9539/t/2/assets/weiss.png?5811407930308074056"/> 
<label for="white"></label>
</div>
```